# Can't access WordPress CMS dashboard via wp-admin login

Tags: php, wordpress

i don't know why but I can't access my wordpress dashboard. I'm using latest version.

What I've tried so far:

1. I've checked permisions in database - everything is ok,
2. Prefix in database is ok,
3. I've removed wp-admin and wp-includes and I've uploaded new files from latest version and from 4.5.3 - still nothing,
4. I've renamed plugins folder, themes folder and even all wp-content - still no permission,
5. Any user cant access dashboard - not only admin

After logging in I'm redirected to home page instead of wp-admin. After login the admin bar is visible but without admin options and the link with my page name leads to home page not home page/wp-admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the url in the db. Wordpress hardcodes the url of you page. If you migrated from dev-environment you need to change that

Comment: siteurl and home are correct.

Comment: errorlog of apache and php also clean?

Comment: Start with the error log review. Whatever the problem it should be logged in there.

Comment: How can I get the log file?

Comment: Depends on your os. On linux it's probably `/var/log/apache2`

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced a similar issue last week, but the MD5-hash reset for the user-admin password proved to be the best remediation as advised by the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password). If you're uncomfortable with the command-line and unfamiliar with Python, I recommend the following solution via phpMyAdmin:

1. Begin by logging into phpMyAdmin and clicking **databases**.
2. A list of databases will appear. Click your WordPress database.
3. All the tables in your database will appear. If not, click **Structure**.
4. Look for **wp_users** in the Table column.
5. Click on the icon for **browse**.
6. Locate your Username under user_login.
7. Click **edit** (may look like a pencil icon in some versions of phpMyAdmin).
8. Your user_id will be shown, click on Edit.
9. Next to the user_pass is a long list of numbers and letters.
10. Select and delete these and type in your new password.
11. Type in the password you want to use. Just type it in normally, but remember, it is case-sensitive.
12. In this example, the new password will be 'rabbitseatcarrots'.
13. Once you have done that, click the dropdown menu indicated, and select **MD5** from the menu.
14. Check that your password is actually correct, and that MD5 is in the box.
15. Click the 'Go' button to the bottom right.
16. Test the new password on the login screen. If it doesn't work, check that you've followed these instructions exactly.
17. You should be able to access the WordPress CMS with the reset credentials for user-admin.  Next time try the command-line; it's not that bad!  :D